# Spring + JPA transaction is created and commited but no result in db

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I've read many threads complaining to similar issue but none of them help me in my case. Anyway, the problem is that I have written a few classes:

**Person entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Person setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Person setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Person)) {
            return false;
        }
        Person other = (Person) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.myhome.event_manager.entity.Person[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

**PersonDAO:**

```
@Repository
public class PersonDAO extends AbstractDAO<Person> {


    public PersonDAO() {
        setClazz(Person.class);
    }

    public Person findByName(String name) {
        return em.createQuery("WHERE p.name = :name", Person.class)
            .setParameter("name", name)
            .getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

**AbstractDAO:**

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T extends Serializable> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="pu-main")
protected EntityManager em;
protected Class< T> clazz;

public void setClazz(final Class< T> clazzToSet) {
    this.clazz = clazzToSet;
}

public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}

public EntityManager getEm() {
    return em;
}

public T findById(final Long id) {
    return this.em.find(this.clazz, id);
}

public List< T> findAll() {
    return this.em.createQuery("from " + this.clazz.getName())
            .getResultList();
}

public void create(final T entity) {
    this.em.persist(entity);
}

public void update(final T entity) {
    this.em.merge(entity);
}

public void delete(final T entity) {
    this.em.remove(entity);
}

public void deleteById(final Long entityId) {
    final T entity = this.findById(entityId);
    this.delete(entity);
}
```

}

and simple **PersonService** which is in this case a wrapper to DAO with a @Transactional method createPerson:

```
@Service
public class PersonService {

@Autowired
private PersonDAO personDao;

@Transactional
public void createPerson(Person person) {
    personDao.create(person);
}

public List<Person> listAllPersons() {
    return personDao.findAll();
}

public Person getPersonWithName(String name) {
    return personDao.findByName(name);
}
```

}

**pom.xml:**

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Mysql driver-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Hibernate-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--JSTL-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

All above works along with configuration included in root-context.xml:

**DataSource.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!--MysQL - main-->
<bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
</bean>

<bean id="emFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu-main" />
</bean>
```

**Transactions.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

<!--enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations--> 
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

<!--Transactions-->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

**persistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="pu-main" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source/>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Next I made a jUnit test that creates new Person instance, and calls create method of PersonService which should pass it down to DAO and persistence layer.

Test:

```
public class PersonServiceTest extends RootContextAwareTest {

@Autowired
private PersonService instance;

@Test
public void shouldAddOnePerson() {
    logger.debug("TEST-shouldAddOnePerson");

    //given
    Person person = (new Person())
            .setName("Test");

    //when
    logger.debug("BEFORE CREATE");
    instance.createPerson(person);
    logger.debug("AFTER CREATE");


    //then
    assertThat(instance.listAllPersons()).hasSize(6);
    assertThat(instance.getPersonWithName("Test"));
}
```

}

RootContextAwareTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/config/spring/root-context.xml"})
public abstract class RootContextAwareTest {
     protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RootContextAwareTest.class);
}
```

Acctually there are 5 rows in person table so I simply put an assertion after persisting of new entity that checks if it was persisted properly. As it turned out it wasn't and assertion failed but to my amazement logs say that everything goes fine:

```
    2013-01-28 21:28:07,148 - DEBUG: com.myhome.event_manager.test_base.RootContextAwareTest - TEST-shouldAddOnePerson
2013-01-28 21:28:07,148 - DEBUG: com.myhome.event_manager.test_base.RootContextAwareTest - BEFORE CREATE
2013-01-28 21:28:07,154 - DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.myhome.event_manager.service.PersonService.createPerson]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2013-01-28 21:28:07,155 - DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/event_manager]
2013-01-28 21:28:07,172 - DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquired Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@164a38ae] for JDBC transaction
2013-01-28 21:28:07,178 - DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@164a38ae] to manual commit
2013-01-28 21:28:07,208 - DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Opening JPA EntityManager
2013-01-28 21:28:07,249 - DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
2013-01-28 21:28:07,267 - DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
2013-01-28 21:28:07,268 - DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
2013-01-28 21:28:07,269 - DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@164a38ae]
2013-01-28 21:28:07,269 - DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@164a38ae] after transaction
2013-01-28 21:28:07,269 - DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2013-01-28 21:28:07,270 - DEBUG: com.myhome.event_manager.test_base.RootContextAwareTest - AFTER CREATE
```

So I thought (after some research) that test env doesn't allow any changes to db by default (which would be quite logical).
So my second attempt was to add annotations:

```
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManager", defaultRollback = false)
```

on a PersonServiceTest class. Result was like just like before transaction created, committed, and released without any error. I've made up some research again and made a simple controller and put there code which should create and persist new person entity.

**MainController:**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainController.class);
    private ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/config/spring/root-context.xml");
    @Autowired
    private PersonService ps;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        Person person = (new Person())
                .setName("Test-ąęć");

        logger.debug("PERSIST PERSON");
        ps.createPerson(person);
        return "forward:/event/read";
    }
}
```

The result was the same as above.

I've tried also putting @Transactional annotation do DAO (class and method level) and controller.

That kind of behavior should point on problem with configuration of persistence layer but selecting of data from db works fine.

Also I've come across opionion that hibernate may have some delay before writing data to db so I've added thread.sleep(5000) in test but it doesn't change much.

Maybe I've missed something in configuration but I've run out of ideas right now.

I would be appreciated for any help.

Comment: Are you're sure you're connecting to the right database? I would doble-check. Also, change your test to check what the number of persons is before persisting a new one, and check that you have one more after persisting it.

Comment: I have checked it more than twice. I have also put assertion before persisting data to check if it can fetch 5 existing rows in db and it was ok but assertion after persistence which was up to check if there are 6 rows failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm your problem looks complex, however I realized you used DatasourceTransactionManager on your Transactions.xml, while you seem to be using JPA persistence.

Maybe try using JpaTransactionManager instead. Maybe DatasourceTransactionManager isn't giving you the right transaction on methods you annotated with @Transactional

Comment: That's the point! As always the problem is too obvious to spot it straight away! I was following spring "Transaction Management" chapter of Spring framework reference where it isn't (at least for me when I read it) described clearly enough. Instead there is an example which uses DataSourceTransactionManager so I just do the same and didn't focus on it. After your post I looked to Spring in Action and there was vary nice table and graph showing when to use which transaction manager class. I have changed it to JpaTransactionManager and data is persisted to db without any problem. Thanks.

Comment: Also if you use Spring Roo, you can create a new project complete with JPA Hibernate setup, you can use it as a reference / sample project. Setting up a new Spring project from scratch is a tricky business

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with ORM mapping, you should always make sure to *flush* your `EntityManager` (or Hibernate session if you are using that instead of JPA) to avoid [false positives](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx-false-positives) before making your assertions, e.g.

```
@Transactional
public class PersonServiceTest {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        // given (initialization)

        // when (write stuff to be persisted)

        em.flush();

        // then (read and validate)
    }
}
```

Comment: This results in a javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress even if I add @Transactional to class/method of a test

Comment: Imho, depending on your use- / test-case, I would add `@Transactional` to both the service class and the class that tests the service. Hereby, you can tailor the [rollback](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx) after each test (typically, rollback after each test, so that next test relies on a known state).

Comment: I agree - test should not influence each other and making test transactional and rollback is good way to achieve this. Also I often use diffrent db for tests (for example HSQLDB) included in base test class. This way I don't make changes to main db with no risk to mess things up. Sources I provided were up to ilustrate my particular problem with persisting so I included only necessary code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Person Id column in your db allowing null?  If so, the newly created Person may be 'equal' to an existing row.  This would cause an update, not an insert.

Comment: id in person table have PK, NN and AI attributes, so I would expect that leaving null in application would result in adding new row with id assigned by db.